# Pandas DataFrame -Extraction rows by using iterative condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, data-extraction

I have probably simple but for me tough question.

So, I have data like below:

```
table = pd.DataFrame([['AAA', 12333.21, 'buy'], ['BBB', 7683.15, 'buy'], ['AAA', 33.2, 'sell'], ['CCC', 33.2, 'buy']], columns=['Ticker', 'Value', 'Buy or Sell'])
```

and I would like to check in column 'Buy or Sell' which instruments are sold. Extract the "Ticker" for these instruments and create a new Data Frame containing only the instruments for this specific ticker. For above example it is:

| Ticker | Value | Buy or Sell |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 12333.21 | buy |
| AAA | 33.2 | sell |

I started with following code:

```
marker = table[table["Buy or Sell"]=="sell"]
marker_final = marker.loc[:,"Ticker"]
```

But after that whenever I continue it does not work for example:

```
table[table["Ticker"] == marker_final]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset `table` by all of the unique values in the `'Ticker'` column of `marker`:

```
marker_final = table[table['Ticker'].isin(marker['Ticker'].unique())]
```

Result:

```
  Ticker     Value Buy or Sell
0    AAA  12333.21         buy
2    AAA     33.20        sell
```